# Fill Variable with Web Service Results

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

I have a javascript function that is executed onClick via jquery. Within this function I am calling a Web Service "getTestConnection" which returns a True or False and I have confirmed it is working but keeps returning variable undefined.

```js
      $("#btnNext2").click(function() {
        var postData = {}; {
          postData['user'] = user;
          postData['password'] = password;
          postData['serviceurl'] = serviceurl;
          postData['datasource'] = datasource;
        };
        //Converts object to string and formats to JSON
        var json = JSON.stringify(postData);

        //connTest keeps getting returned as 'Undefined'
        var connTest = getTestConnection(json);

      });


       < script type = "text/javascript" >
        function getDocType(json, rowcount) {

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:64580/Web_Services/WebServiceLibrary.asmx/GetDocTypes",
            data: json,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

              //*****************************************************************************
              //This is being called immediately after getTestConnection is executed
              //******************************************************************************         
              for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                $('#SelectDocType' + rowcount + '')
                  .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", data.d[i].docTypeID)
                    .text(data.d[i].docTypeName));
              }
              var firstDocTypeID = data.d[0].docTypeID;
              var jsonUnstringify = JSON.parse(json);
              var postDataNew = {}; {
                postDataNew['user'] = jsonUnstringify.user;
                postDataNew['password'] = jsonUnstringify.password;
                postDataNew['serviceurl'] = jsonUnstringify.serviceurl;
                postDataNew['datasource'] = jsonUnstringify.datasource;
                postDataNew['docTypeID'] = firstDocTypeID;
              };
              var jsonnew = JSON.stringify(postDataNew);

              getKeywords(jsonnew, rowcount);

            },
            error: function(data) {
              alert("***********Error***********" + data.responseText);
            },
            failure: function(data) {
              alert("***********Failure***********" + data.responseText);
            }
          });
          //Test Connection Web Service
          function getTestConnection(json) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:64580/Web_Services/WebServiceLibrary.asmx/TestConnection",
                data: json,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

                if (data.d == 'True') {

                  return true;
                } else {
                  return false;

                }

              },
              error: function(data) {
                alert("***********Error***********" + data.responseText);
              },
              failure: function(data) {
                alert("***********Failure***********" + data.responseText);
              }
            });
        }

       < /script>
```

Comment: you have a `<script>` tag within javascript code. that's not valid.

Comment: Did you forgot `success: function(data) {}` in your ajax call `getTestConnection` ? Also it seems you have a function in another function that's not valid.

Comment: is there a typo in your js code or did you write another script tag in your js code ?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiples errors:

1. You have a `<script type = "text/javascript">` tag inside another `<script>` tag
2. You define a new function inside another function:

`function getDocType(json, rowcount) {
    $.ajax({
       .....
    });
    function getTestConnection(json) {
       ....
    }
}`

which should be

```
function getDocType(json, rowcount) {
    $.ajax({
       .....
    });
}
function getTestConnection(json) {
   ....
}
```

3. You forgot to get returned data from the AJAX call in your getTestConnection function :

`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost...",
        data: json,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.d == 'True') {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            ....
        }
});`

Comment: Ugh I messed up when I copy and pasted the web service call. Thanks!